# MySQL 'SHOW TABLES' Returns count instead of list (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm troubleshooting a script I am using to query the database. To make sure I had everything working right I stripped it down to a simple 'SHOW TABLES' query. The problem is that it is returning a count of the tables instead of the list of names it should return.

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host='10.0.0.208', user='admin', passwd='Passwrd')

cursor = connection.cursor()
sqlstring = 'SHOW TABLES;'
cursor.execute('USE CustDB')
x = cursor.execute(sqlstring)

print(x)
```

This is only returning '17'. What am I missing??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute), `execute` returns the number of rows affected

> Returns: Number of affected rows

In order to get the desired results, you need to loop through the `cursor`

```
cursor.execute('USE CustDB')
tables = [c for c in cursor]
```

or use `fetchall`

```
cursor.execute('USE CustDB')
tables = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: That did it. Thankyou

Comment: It was the fetchall() line I missed. I know I have done this a bunch of times before without the loop. fetchall() fixed it. Thankyou. Ill mark this as correct once the timer lets me

Comment: @Joe I'm glad I could be of assistance